# Tool to nest selectors in LESS files

Tags: less

I am looking for an online tool, command line tool, or Windows application to convert flat selector rules to nested in a LESS file.

Before:

```
#header {
  color: black;
}
#header .navigation {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header .logo {
  width: 300px;
}
```

After:

```
#header {
  color: black;
  .navigation {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [**CSS 2 LESS**](http://css2less.co/):

Pasting your CSS code in left pane, you'll obtain the following LESS on the right one:

```
#header {
    color: black;
    .navigation {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .logo {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

that is exactly what do you expect